# simple question about an endomorphism of third order

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f$ is an endomorphism on $R^3$ such that $f\neq Id, f^3=Id$, the identity map, why is it immediate that $x^3-1$ is the characteristic polynomial of $f$? Since $x^3-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2)$ wouldn't one first have to show that $Id+f+f^2\neq 0?$

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial of a linear map $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ has degree $3$.

Comment: (You are probably thinking of the minimal polynomial)